# CDF player crashes

Tags: cdfplayer

*UPDATE:
Was asked by Wolfram technical support to try another CDF file but that too failed, was asked to provide `SystemInformation[]` and CDF version number.
New version of CDF: 11.0.1.1 have been released, I haven't tried it yet. May be they solved the problem with this new version*.

---

CDF Player Version: 11.0.1.0

[image: 3]

Opening a CDF file directly crashes the player.

[image: 1]

Whereas it works if you open the CDF application and use the 'Open' feature to open a CDF file.
[image: 2]

Comment: @Kuba sent. Will update here, if there is any progress from the development team.